# set Windows Defender protection in manual mode in Windows 10

Tags: command-line, windows-10, windows-services, windows-defender

I would like to set the Windows Defender protection service in **manual** mode (NOT disabled completely) so that:

- when Windows starts it is disabled
- i can run custom scans with `MpCmdRun.exe`
- i can temporally enable or disable protection according to my needs with some command like `net start ...`

Comment: I honestly don't believe this is possible with Windows Defender.  If you want this type of fine control I suggest a commercial product.

Comment: I've found a partial answer [here](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/3569-windows-defender-real-time-protection-turn-off-windows-10-a.html#option3), now i just need to know how to start the real-time protection from the commandline..